# Making wine to be compiled with libxml2 support on gentoo

Tags: wine, gentoo

Despite I had **xml** use flag in my make.conf and **installed libxml2** before compiling wine sometimes I'm getting errors like this:

```
This program tried to use a DOMDocument object, but
libxml2 support was not present at compile time.
```

Looks like wine got compiled without libxml2 support.
How to make wine compiled with libxml2 on gentoo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's find out if you built wine with the xml use flag enabled in the past.
If you have eix installed you could run

```
eix -e wine
```

to see.  If not you could try

```
less /var/db/pkg/app-emulation/wine-*/USE
```

to see the list of applied use flags.